# How to store items recursively?

Tags: php

I want to collect& store data into an array while drilling into some structured data, so that when I am done, I have an array like this for ex::

```
[{nodes:[{nodes:[], id:2}, {nodes:[{nodes:[], id:4}], id:3} ], id:1}]
```

Notice how I store deeper nodes into parent nodes,Here is my attempt simplified, as I tried to pass node by reference to be able to collect deeper nodes into their parent nodes:

```
$parentNode= array('nodes'=>array());
scan ($parentNode, $excel, 0, 0);

function scan (& $parentNode, $excel, $row, $column, $maxColumn)
{
    $childNode = array('nodes' => array(), 'id' => $excel[$row]['cr'.$column]);

    // to make sure I am drilling as expected, I used echo:
    echo ($newNode['id'].',');
    // now, push the child node into the passed by reference parent node:
    array_push($parentNode['nodes'], $childNode);
    // keep drilling, pass child node as parent:
    $this->scan($childNode, $excel, $row, $column + 1, $maxColumn);
}
```

But, what I get is:

```
{nodes:[{nodes:[],id:1}]}
```

Why wouldn't I get what I expect? As long as I pass childNode by reference, I should be able to build my pyramid of nodes based on first passed node, right?

Comment: [__`json_encode()`__](http://php.net/json_encode) ?

Comment: I want to store my data into a hashed array, before I use json_encode, when I get it properly, I would use json_encode next to store the result, but not before I get the results I want

Comment: It's painful to understand how you plan to work: please provide information (and maybe some example) about the `$excel` structure. Note that in its current state your code seems pretty strange: 1) what is this `$this` object? 2) the `scan()` signature has 4 arguments but you invoke it with 5 arguments.

Comment: I've fixed the signature for scan to have 5 args, $this stands for the class in which I use the code, $excel is the result of reading an excel file using laravel-excel package, what I need is to know, how would I store values deeply in child nodes of the same array? why & didn't work?